# Add milliseconds to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, timer, countdown, countdowntimer

I created a simple game for which I need a countdown. Now everything is fine, but I need to add a millisecond to the timer. I used the code found on the internet, but it lacks just those milliseconds. My attempts have not been successful, so I am asking you for help.

```
var seconds;
var temp;

function countdown() {
    time = document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML;
    timeArray = time.split(':')
    seconds = timeToSeconds(timeArray);
    if (seconds == '') {
        temp = document.getElementById('countdown');
        temp.innerHTML = '00:00:00';
        return;
    }
    seconds--;
    temp = document.getElementById('countdown');
    temp.innerHTML = secondsToTime(seconds);
    timeoutMyOswego = setTimeout(countdown, 1000);
}

function timeToSeconds(timeArray) {
    var minutes = (timeArray[0] * 1);
    var seconds = (minutes * 60) + (timeArray[1] * 1);
    return seconds;
}

function secondsToTime(secs) {
    var divisor_for_minutes = secs % (60 * 60);
    var minutes = Math.floor(divisor_for_minutes / 60);
    minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0' + minutes : minutes;
    var divisor_for_seconds = divisor_for_minutes % 60;
    var seconds = Math.ceil(divisor_for_seconds);
    seconds = seconds < 10 ? '0' + seconds : seconds;
    return minutes + ':' + seconds;
}
countdown();
```

Comment: Please add ***all*** the relevant code (HTML and CSS as well as JavaScript) so that we can replicate your scenario and provide a working solution.

Comment: Do you understand how this code you copied works? What have you tried to modify

Comment: Instead of doing all that by hand, maybe it would be handy to use a library like [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/) that would likely solve most of your problems.

Comment: milliseconds don't really matter if you have a `setTimeout` of 1 second (1000 ms) Your attempt doesn't really show how you tried handling the milisecond, can you add what you have tried till now?